# Overhead/drawback of defining a function with both __device__ and __host__ qualifiers?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Is there any drawback or overhead of defining function with both

```
__host__ __device__
```

qualifier instead of just

```
__device__
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be any drawbacks. If you call the generated binary code for your host function overhead than yes, there will be an overhead increasing your programm size. 
The nvcc compiler driver will build one device function callable from `__global__` and utilize the host compiler to generate one version of your function for host code. Thats it.